# React JS wait for useContext change

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hello how to wait for use context change but i create

Component child:

```js
const [weatherInfo, setWeatherInfo] = useState(useContext(WeatherContext))
```

and it return started useContext update, i update him 5seconds from fetch after starting but its not change in component child

Comment: I don't think you need to put the output of `useContext` into `useState`.

Comment: I think you may be mixing two concepts. You could use `setInterval(() => setWeaitherInfo(), 5000)` to update data on an interface

Comment: Just use the contect value directly, don't copy it into state, when you update the contect the child component will re-render

Answer (score 0):

Don't use useState to store the context data if you want to be aware of changes:

```
const setWeatherInfo = useContext(WeatherContext)
```